# MailChimp API v2: Validation Error

Tags: php, curl, mailchimp

I have this problem with Mailchimp that my call seems to be denied and fail. Somehow Mailchimp Support can not even see that I tried to call them with this code

```
$data = array(
    'apikey' => "APIKEY-USXX",
    'cid' => "CID",
);
$data = json_encode($data);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data);
echo '</pre>';

$submit_url = "https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/reports/opened.json";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($data));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$info = json_decode(json_encode(json_decode($result)), true);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($info);
echo '</pre>';
```

The strange thing is, this works just fine for any other call i make with API 1.3. I'm really lost in what iam doing wrong here. Hope you guys can help me?

Thanks in advance.

** EDIT **
Here is my response:

```
array(4) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(5) "error"
  ["code"]=>
  int(-100)
  ["name"]=>
  string(15) "ValidationError"
  ["error"]=>
  string(31) "You must specify a apikey value"
}
```

Final code that worked for me:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'MailChimp-PHP/2.0.6');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: 2 fast things that come to my mind here: have you tried to use the official mc api v2 php wrapper? And maybe you can try to specify the json content type header (which seems not to be in your code)

Comment: Are you sure you have to url encode your post fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the 'dc' in the submit URL (us10) matches the last portion of your API key.

Also... try adding the following options to the call:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'MailChimp-PHP/2.0.6');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

You can also add the following option to debug the call more explicitly

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

Comment: This answer with the comment from @Parris Varney about removing the url_encode helped me to retrieve the right result. Thanks guys!