# How to validate Mailchimp API key in PHP?

Tags: php, validation, mailchimp

How to validate Mailchimp API key if it is valid or existing in Mailchimp. I want to save this key on database and before that I need to validate given key. I see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625869/mailchimp-api-v2-validation-error) and follow it and it is not working on me. It show nothing.

Here is my code:

```
validateApiKey('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us1');

function validateApiKey($api_key)
{
$data = array(
    'apikey' => $api_key,
    'cid' => "CID",
);
$data = json_encode($data);


$submit_url = "https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/reports/opened.json";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'MailChimp-PHP/2.0.6');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$info = json_decode(json_encode(json_decode($result)), true);
print_r($info);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($info);
echo '</pre>';

}
```

How to know if the key is valid or not. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a request. If the request works, the key is valid. In v2.0, you can use the `/2.0/helper/ping` endpoint. In 3.0, the root (`/3.0/`) is similar.

Comment: where would I put this "/2.0/helper/ping" ? How would I do that? Thanks

Comment: Here are the [docs](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/helper/ping.php) for that call. You'd use it the same way you're using `reports/opened` in the example code.